# are there dictionaries in javascript like python?

Tags: javascript, python

i need to make a dictionary in javascript like this

i dont remember the exact notation, but it was something like:

```
states_dictionary={ CT=[alex,harry], AK=[liza,alex], TX=[fred, harry] ........ }
```

is there such a thing in javascript?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130543/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-hashtable-implementation-in-javascript

Comment: The answer you accepted is very wrong.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Which errors did you notice in that answer?

Comment: I see it is edited after I commented. It seems : was missing

Comment: Read most recent answer for ES6 Maps http://stackoverflow.com/a/32993723/1993919 (commenting for same reason it was posted)

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen how about go to the answer section and comment proving which part is wrong, because im confused

Answer (score 171, accepted):

This is an old post, but I thought I should provide an illustrated answer anyway.

Use javascript's object notation. Like so:

```
states_dictionary={ 
     "CT":["alex","harry"], 
     "AK":["liza","alex"], 
     "TX":["fred", "harry"]
};
```

And to access the values:

```
states_dictionary.AK[0] //which is liza
```

or you can use javascript literal object notation, whereby the keys not require to be in quotes:

```
states_dictionary={ 
     CT:["alex","harry"], 
     AK:["liza","alex"], 
     TX:["fred", "harry"]
};
```

Comment: it's worth noting that the first example should yield the same object in both languages using exactly same syntax except the closing ';'.
  states_dictionary={ 
     "CT":["alex","harry"], 
     "AK":["liza","alex"], 
     "TX":["fred", "harry"]
  }

Comment: I am more used to the literal object notation, since you access them in the same way what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou the main difference is javascript object notation keys must be strings (enclosed in double quotes " " ). The object notation is as seen in JSON for data interchage and was inspired by the literal object notation; it is worth noting that JSON is usually used in string context

Comment: Actually, Python allows statement-terminating semicolons, so the first example is completely valid both in Python and JavaScript

Comment: If the value comes from the user, then care needs to be taken to use `Object.hasOwnProperty.call(dictionary, key)` (otherwise the user can enter a value of *valueOf* and `dictionary['valueOf']` returns the `Object.valueOf()` function belonging to the Object prototype which is probably not what your code would expect - potential bug or security issue). If the key is not a string type, then care needs to be taken, otherwise the implicit numeric and toString conversions will cause you problems. The ES6 `Map` type has been designed to provide extended functionality for dictionaries.

Answer (score 76):

There were no real associative arrays in Javascript until 2015 (release of ECMAScript 6). Since then you can use the Map object as Robocat states. [Look up the details in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Example:

```
let map = new Map();
map.set('key', {'value1', 'value2'});
let values = map.get('key');
```

Without support for ES6 you can try using objects:

```
var x = new Object();
x["Key"] = "Value";
```

However with objects it is not possible to use typical array properties or methods like array.length. At least it is possible to access the "object-array" in a for-in-loop.

Comment: What about the performance? is looking up a key in an object constant time?

Comment: Since o["key"] is equivalent to o.key in Javascript the performance is almost the same. However performance depends on the Javascript Engine / Webbrowser. There are quite a lot differences between these, especially in the older versions.

Comment: ECMAScript 6 defines an official Map object (i.e. "There are no real associative arrays in Javascript" is now incorrect).

Answer (score 42):

In ECMAScript 6, the official [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object has been introduced, which is a dictionary implementation:

```
let dict = new Map();
dict.set("foo", "bar");

//returns "bar"
dict.get("foo");
```

Unlike javascript's normal objects, it allows any object as a key using identity comparison:

```
let foo = {};
let bar = {};
let dict = new Map();
dict.set(foo, "Foo");
dict.set(bar, "Bar");

//returns "Bar"
dict.get(bar);

//returns "Foo"
dict.get(foo);

//returns undefined, as {} !== foo and {} !== bar
dict.get({});
```

There is no way to have a user defined key comparator, so if you do not desire identity comparison, you are still stuck with only using number or string keys like with a normal object.

Comment: Works for me, nice to use a cleaner ES6 method. Thank you!

Follow up, de we know any way to "bulk set()", e.g. like python `dict = { key: value)`?

Answer (score 11):

Have created a simple dictionary in JS here:

```
function JSdict() {
    this.Keys = [];
    this.Values = [];
}

// Check if dictionary extensions aren't implemented yet.
// Returns value of a key
if (!JSdict.prototype.getVal) {
    JSdict.prototype.getVal = function (key) {
        if (key == null) {
            return "Key cannot be null";
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < this.Keys.length; i++) {
            if (this.Keys[i] == key) {
                return this.Values[i];
            }
        }
        return "Key not found!";
    }
}


// Check if dictionary extensions aren't implemented yet.
// Updates value of a key
if (!JSdict.prototype.update) {
    JSdict.prototype.update = function (key, val) {
        if (key == null || val == null) {
            return "Key or Value cannot be null";
        }
        // Verify dict integrity before each operation
        if (keysLength != valsLength) {
            return "Dictionary inconsistent. Keys length don't match values!";
        }
        var keysLength = this.Keys.length;
        var valsLength = this.Values.length;
        var flag = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < keysLength; i++) {
            if (this.Keys[i] == key) {
                this.Values[i] = val;
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            return "Key does not exist";
        }
    }
}



// Check if dictionary extensions aren't implemented yet.
// Adds a unique key value pair
if (!JSdict.prototype.add) {
    JSdict.prototype.add = function (key, val) {
        // Allow only strings or numbers as keys
        if (typeof (key) == "number" || typeof (key) == "string") {
            if (key == null || val == null) {
                return "Key or Value cannot be null";
            }
            if (keysLength != valsLength) {
                return "Dictionary inconsistent. Keys length don't match values!";
            }
            var keysLength = this.Keys.length;
            var valsLength = this.Values.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < keysLength; i++) {
                if (this.Keys[i] == key) {
                    return "Duplicate keys not allowed!";
                }
            }
            this.Keys.push(key);
            this.Values.push(val);
        }
        else {
            return "Only number or string can be key!";
        }
    }
}

// Check if dictionary extensions aren't implemented yet.
// Removes a key value pair
if (!JSdict.prototype.remove) {
    JSdict.prototype.remove = function (key) {
        if (key == null) {
            return "Key cannot be null";
        }
        if (keysLength != valsLength) {
            return "Dictionary inconsistent. Keys length don't match values!";
        }
        var keysLength = this.Keys.length;
        var valsLength = this.Values.length;
        var flag = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < keysLength; i++) {
            if (this.Keys[i] == key) {
                this.Keys.shift(key);
                this.Values.shift(this.Values[i]);
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            return "Key does not exist";
        }
    }
}
```

### The above implementation can now be used to simulate a dictionary as:

```
var dict = new JSdict();

dict.add(1, "one")

dict.add(1, "one more")
"Duplicate keys not allowed!"

dict.getVal(1)
"one"

dict.update(1, "onne")

dict.getVal(1)
"onne"

dict.remove(1)

dict.getVal(1)
"Key not found!"
```

This is just a basic simulation.
It can be further optimized by implementing a better running time algorithm to work in atleast O(nlogn) time complexity or even less. Like merge/quick sort on arrays and then some B-search for lookups.
I Didn't give a try or searched about mapping a hash function in JS.

Also, Key and Value for the JSdict obj can be turned into private variables to be sneaky.

Hope this helps!

EDIT >>
After implementing the above, I personally used the JS objects as associative arrays that are available out-of-the-box.

*However*, I would like to make a special mention about two methods that actually proved helpful to make it a convenient hashtable experience.

Viz: **dict.hasOwnProperty(key)** *and* **delete dict[key]**

Read this post as a good resource on this implementation/usage. 
[Dynamically creating keys in JavaScript associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351495/dynamically-creating-keys-in-javascript-associative-array)

THanks!

Answer (score 7):

Use JavaScript objects. You can access their properties like keys in a dictionary. This is the foundation of JSON. The syntax is similar to Python dictionaries. See: [JSON.org](http://JSON.org)

Comment: "Watch" out! Object prototype methods like "watch" can bite you this way. Even if you don't have any of those, you'll at least have "[constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007275/javascript-reserved-word-and-object)".

Answer (score 4):

An old question but I recently needed to do an AS3>JS port, and for the sake of speed I wrote a simple AS3-style Dictionary object for JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/MickMalone1983/VEpFf/2/

If you didn't know, the AS3 dictionary allows you to use any object as the key, as opposed to just strings. They come in very handy once you've found a use for them.

It's not as fast as a native object would be, but I've not found any significant problems with it in that respect.

API:

```
//Constructor
var dict = new Dict(overwrite:Boolean);

//If overwrite, allows over-writing of duplicate keys,
//otherwise, will not add duplicate keys to dictionary.

dict.put(key, value);//Add a pair
dict.get(key);//Get value from key
dict.remove(key);//Remove pair by key
dict.clearAll(value);//Remove all pairs with this value
dict.iterate(function(key, value){//Send all pairs as arguments to this function:
    console.log(key+' is key for '+value);
});


dict.get(key);//Get value from key
```

Comment: Nice and useful library! I have added a get function, which I thought was missing and fixed some minor syntax issues (missing semicolon etc). Here's the modified fiddle: [Dictionary in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evPhE/3/)

Comment: Good job mate, dunno why that wasn't in there!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 13+ provides an experimental implementation of the `map` object similar to the `dict` object in python. [Specifications here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FMap).

It's only avaible in firefox, but it looks better than using attributes of a `new Object()`. Citation from the documentation :

> - An Object has a prototype, so there are default keys in the map. However, this can be bypassed using `map = Object.create(null)`.
> - The keys of an `Object` are `Strings`, where they can be any value for a `Map`.
> - You can get the size of a `Map` easily while you have to manually keep track of size for an `Object`.