# Performance of key lookup in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hash

I just read this question: [are there dictionaries in javascript like python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559070/are-there-dictionaries-in-javascript-like-python)

One of the answers said that you can use JavaScript objects like Python dictionaries. Is that true? What is the performance of a key lookup in an object? Is it O(1)? Is adding a key to the object also constant time (hashing)?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The [V8 design docs](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/design.html) imply lookups  will be at least this fast, if not faster:

> **Most JavaScript engines use a dictionary-like data structure as
>   storage for object properties** - each property access requires a
>   dynamic lookup to resolve the property's location in memory. This
>   approach makes accessing properties in JavaScript typically much
>   slower than accessing instance variables in programming languages like
>   Java and Smalltalk. In these languages, instance variables are located
>   at fixed offsets determined by the compiler due to the fixed object
>   layout defined by the object's class. Access is simply a matter of a
>   memory load or store, often requiring only a single instruction.
>
> To reduce the time required to access JavaScript properties, V8 does
>   not use dynamic lookup to access properties. Instead, V8 dynamically
>   creates hidden classes behind the scenes. [...] **In V8, an object changes
>   its hidden class when a new property is added.**

It sounds like adding a new key might be slightly slower, though, due to the hidden class creation.

Comment: Thanks Domenic! so it seems to be safe for me to use Object lookups as dictionary lookups if I am doing more lookups than hashing.

Comment: For V8, is it true that dynamic lookup is not used for both the dot notation as well as the square brackets notation?

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you can assume that adding a key, and later using it for access are *effectively* constant time operations.

Under the hood the JS engine may apply some techniques to optimize subsequent lookups, but for the purposes of any algorithm, you can assume O(1).

Comment: Compare with `var first = new Map([
  [1, 'one'],
  [2, 'two'],
  [3, 'three'],
]);` How efficient is `var second={'1': one, '2': two, '3': 'three'}`?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at a similar question [How does JavaScript VM implements Object property access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6586670/4858777) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62064106/4858777). Here I described the optimization technique used by JS engines and how it affects the key lookup performance. I hope these details help you write more efficient JS code.