# More than one javascript namespace?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I was wondering whether there is any associated performance problems with using only *one* namespace or whether assigning more than one is better ?

By this I mean

```
(function (myApp, $, undefined) {

} (window.myApp = window.myApp || {}, jQuery));
```

And assign *every* function / object / property to the `myApp` namespace or whether it is more efficent from a performance perspective to have `myApp` for common functions etc and then have

```
(function (myAppSettings, $, undefined) {

} (window.myAppSettings = window.myAppSettings || {}, jQuery));
```

And so forth ?

**Edit**: to clarify the generic `settings` to `myAppSettings` per @pimvdb very correct comment

Comment: Your question does not make sense, can you clarify a bit more

Comment: Hey thanks :) What I mean is - are there any performance issues assign 100 or more functions to the myApp namespace ? If yes, it is better to simply use multiple differing namespace ? Such as `myApp` and `settings` etc etc and assign functions to each respectively ?

Comment: 100 items in a hash table is nothing.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin - but surely it would depend on the complexity of the functions. I have a pretty heavy JS app - with deep object and property tree's - I'm just wondering whether it's better to perhaps remove some from the current `myApp` namespace to another

Comment: Do what makes your code most clear/usable. Don't worry about performance in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a shallow tree is better than a deep tree (citation [from here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/)). So, depending on the circumstances, it *may* be better to use more than one namespace. The cited article claims a single namespace is negligible in terms of perfomance though.

Comment: hey :) thanks - the link is broken ? really interested to read a bit into this if you can fix it ?

Comment: great link. thanks heaps - generally it seems that its OK for now. I'm not `YAHOO` - so I dont think my tree's are as complex as theirs! The last paragraph answered my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any difference from a performance point of view. Getting an object property [is O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700987/performance-of-key-lookup-in-javascript-object-hashing) in today's implementations.

But a name like `settings` is so generic you'd better not make it collide with another library's `settings`. Since these settings are part of `myApp`, it makes most sense (and it is most safest) to put it in the `myApp` object.

If every library would be setting `window.settings`, that would be a big issue.

Comment: ah right - yep, just an example thanks for the tip however. Generally, I was going to use a derivation of like `myAppSettings` etc