# Do browsers(etc) **internally optimize** their retrieval of javascript object properties?

Tags: javascript, object

Additional Note:

I did check this previous answer and desire an answer that is more current and that is less Chrome specific: [Performance of key lookup in JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700987/performance-of-key-lookup-in-javascript-object)

Assuming a standard javascript “dictionary” object with properties like this:

```
var myObject = {
   Key1: ”Value1”,
   Key2: ”Value2”,
   Key3: ”Value3”,
   …
   Key500: ”Value500”
}
```

Does anyone know if browsers(etc) **internally optimize** their retrieval of these properties?

A good case might be auto-sort + binary search.

A not-so-good case might be simple linear search.

EcmaScript standards say the browsers can do the internals as they wish:

> [browsers,etc] may support [object’s] internal properties with any
>   implementation-dependent behaviour as long as it is consistent with
>   the specific host object restrictions stated in this document.

and

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties …  is not
>   specified.

I'm not really needing to know a specific optimization, I just want to know if they are trying to optimize beyond a simple linear search.

So, does anyone have "inside" knowledge?

Comment: Of course they do optimize search by key. It's an essential point. Some engine even compile objects as kind of classes in certain cases.

Comment: I suspect you're right...but do you have knowledge that they optimize, or are you assuming they do?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700987/performance-of-key-lookup-in-javascript-object

Comment: More generally, google for the names of JS engines and "key lookup", "maps" and so on.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence suggests that browsers keep the properties in the order in which they are defined, evidenced by looking at the result of `JSON.stringify(yourObject)`.  The properties in the JSON string are in the same order in which you defined them on the object.  So it doesn't look like they sort the properties.

Comment: @Brandon Not really : they build a structure for fast look-up *and* keep the insertion order (and all say it's not guaranteed)

Comment: @dystroy: yes, I checked that previous answer.  It is 1+ year and a few browser versions ago.

Comment: @markE And did you expect engines to have dropped optimizations since ?

Comment: @dystroy:  be nice!  No, I would expect browser improvements.  The previous answer denoted that browser javascript was **not** well optimized in this regard and said that Chrome was trying to do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The specification does not require such optimications, as you have already noted, but it can be observed empirically. I tested how quickly keys are grabbed from objects that contain up to 500,000 elements. ([test here](http://jsfiddle.net/bE6GR/2/), be warned that it will freeze your browser for a little while).

The key retrieval time does not increase with the size of the object, which means that it has `O(1)` time complexity for search.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to create this test. I'll try your test in multiple browsers.  Hopefully I'll find O(1) for all browsers!

Comment: Found O(1) across all browsers I could get my hands on.  Thanks, I consider that definitive.  Or should I say inductive since it's comes from empirical analysis ;)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the browser and the JavaScript engine. Google's V8 dynamically creates *hidden classes* instead of dynamic lookup, to reduce the time used to access properties. Using hidden classes also has the added benefit of using class-based optimizations such as inline caching.

There is more information [here](https://developers.google.com/v8/design) under the "Fast Property Access" section. The idea basically comes from this paper: [An Efficient Implementation of Self, a Dynamically-Typed Object-Oriented Language Based on Prototypes](http://selflanguage.org/_static/published/implementation.pdf).

Internet Explorer has a "fast type system" to optimize property access. More details [in this presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/4-000).

Mozilla's SpiderMonkey engine uses a [property cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Internals/Property_cache) (warning: the details are somewhat obsolete, but it basically still uses a property cache).

The new IonMonkey engine uses inline property-caches, but details seem to be scant so far.

Comment: Thanks...This is the kind of info I'm hoping for.

Comment: +1 Thanks again for your help. Your answer is equally as valuable as Peter Olson’s and I wish I could give 2 checks.