# How to loop over array of objects and check if name exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have array of objects with about 500 records. I would like to loop trough the array of objects and check if object name is equal to one of the elements. Here is example of my array of objects:

```
data = [
      {
        "row": 23,
        "code": "ERT"
      },
      {
        "row": 45,
        "code": "TTR"
      },
      {
        "row": 90,
        "code": "CXZ"
      }
    ];
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
data.some(function (obj) {
    if(obj.name === "code"){
        return obj[name]; // Return value if name exists
    }
});
```

I would like to check if `name` exists in the object. If does, pull the value for that name. My code will produce `undefined` in the console. Can someone help with this? Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like so:

```
data = [
      {
        "row": 23,
        "code": "ERT"
      },
      {
        "row": 45,
        "code": "TTR"
      },
      {
        "row": 90,
        "code": "CXZ"
      }
    ];


$.each(data, function(index,v) {
 $.each(v, function(key,val) {
    if(key == "code")
       console.log(val)
    }
 });
});
```

Without inner loop:

```
for (var key in data){

  if(key == "code"){
     console.log(key)
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid inner loop for efficiency purposes. Do you have any experience with the solution above? How that will affect the large amount of data?

Comment: Just fixed, you can use second example for no loop. I use it but I also use under 100 objects typically. Try it and find out. Simple google of "Search a JS object" yields 100s of results

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700987/performance-of-key-lookup-in-javascript-object

Comment: Second solution will only provide element number/position. I need the actual name of each element in the object. I hope this make sense. When I loop through I should get `row` and `code` for the name.

Comment: @espresso_coffee  I'm using jsbin right now and that solution returns "ERT"
,"TTR","CXZ". It gives the actual name. editing to show key too then now.

Comment: Those are the values. I need to return `row` or/and `code`.

Comment: Why on earth would you return the word row or code ? That's just the key name which is in every object by default

Comment: Because I might have to return just specific key values. In that case I have to loop and compare key names with the array of column names that will be displayed. I hope this make sense.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Actually all the solutions are correct based in what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can achieve this by `.filter()`, where for each item being filtered, your examine the item's keys (via `Object.keys()`) to see if it contains any of the keys that you're searching/filtering against:

```js
var namesToCompare = ['name', 'code'];

var data = [
      {
        "row": 23,
        "code": "ERT"
      },
      {
        "row": 45,
        "code": "TTR"
      },
      {
        "row": 90,
        "code": "CXZ"
      },
      {
        "row": 91,
        "code": "ABC", 
        "name" : "code"
      }
    ];
    
var result = data
.filter(item => Object
    .keys(item)
    .find(key => namesToCompare.includes(key)))

console.log('items with keys', namesToCompare, 'in list', result);
```

Comment: Can we filter by Value instead of Key here?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const name = "code";
const data = [
      {
        "row": 23,
        "code": "ERT"
      },
      {
        "row": 45,
        "code": "CXZ"
      },
      {
        "row": 90,
        "code": "TTR"
      },
      {
        "row": 190,
        "code": "CXZ"
      }
    ];

const values = [];

data.forEach(element => {
 if (Object.keys(element).includes(name)) {
   values.push(element[name]);
  }
});
    
console.log(values);
```

Object.keys grab all the keys of the object, and then includes searchs the "name" in those keys.

Comment: What if for example I have array of name that I have to compare to the `Object.keys(element)`? Basically instead of comparing just one name, I have to compare multiple names.

Comment: Actually that wasn't part of your question, but... you need another loop to do that.

Comment: I know, my apologies. That's what I realized. Seems like not very efficient solution.

Comment: @espresso_coffee does my answer help with this?