# How can I return only the number of matching pair values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I found a box of loose shoes (all the same kind) at a garage sale, and I've created an array with each individual shoe listed by shoe size.

I want to display the number of paired values of shoe sizes in the array. For example, I have this array:

```
[10,10,10,10,20,20,20,30,50]
```

I would like to display `3` because we have 3 pairs of numbers:

```
10,10
10,10
20,20
```

And 3 remaining values that don't have a matching pair-value (`20,30,50`).

How can I do this?

```js
function pairNumber(arr) {
  var sorted_arr = arr.sort();
  var i;
  var results = [];
  for (i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
      results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }

  }
  return results.length;
}
console.log(pairNumber([10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 50]))
```

Comment: Do you understand why you get 5 instead of 3? If so, then you should be able to fix that.

Comment: Yes I understand, I did fix it since yesterday. Do I have to fix it in the post as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is another approach using a `Set`:

```js
function pairNumbers(arr) {
  let count = 0;
  const set = new Set();

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (set.delete(arr[i])) {
      count++;
    } else {
      set.add(arr[i])
    }
  }

  return count;
}
console.log(pairNumbers([10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 50])) // 3
```

Comment: You can simply omit the `set.has` part as `set.delete` returns what `set.has` would have returned: `if(set.delete(arr[i])){...}else{...}`

Comment: @FZs True, that would be an optimization

Answer (score 8):

I'd reduce into an object, counting up the number of occurrences of each number. Then reduce again on the `Object.values` of the object to count up the number of pairs, adding `Math.floor(count / 2)` to the accumulator on each iteration:

```js
function pairNumber(arr) {
  const itemCounts = arr.reduce((a, item) => {
    a[item] = (a[item] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(itemCounts)
    .reduce((pairsSoFar, count) => pairsSoFar + Math.floor(count / 2), 0);
}
console.log(pairNumber([10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 50]))
```

Probably better to avoid `.sort` if possible - that increases the computational complexity from `O(n)` (minimum) to `O(n log n)`.

Comment: I wonder if building `itemCounts` doesn't add the same `O(nlogn)` back? How do objects work under the hood? Hashtables? Balanced trees?

Comment: For any remotely sane implementation, it'll be `O(1)`, luckily: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700987/performance-of-key-lookup-in-javascript-object . If using an object causes an issue, could use a Map instead

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question well then this can be simplified even further by relying on sort initially...

Increment i to the next position after finding the pair and let the for loop increment it once again.

```
 function pairNumber(arr) {
    const sorted_arr = [...arr].sort(); // disallowing array mutation
    let cnt = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length; i++) {
      if (sorted_arr[i + 1] === sorted_arr[i]) {
        cnt++;
        i = i + 1;
      }

    }
    return cnt;
  }
  console.log(pairNumber([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50]))
  // 5 --> 2 pairs of 10, 2 pairs of 20, 1 pair of 30
  console.log(pairNumbers([10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 50])) 
  // 3 --> 2 pairs of 10 one pair of 20
```

Comment: I believe `sort` will mutate the original array, so a side-effect would be that the array being passed in will be sorted after calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all guys that help me understand more how to solve this issue.
After studying the answers in the post I come up with my own solution.

Thanks to you I understand I should increment *i* at the end of *if* to prevent a repetitive comparison.

```js
function pairNumbers(arr) {
  const sorted_arr = arr.sort();
  const results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i] == sorted_arr[i + 1]) {
      results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
      i = i + 1; 
    }
  }
  return results.length;
}
console.log(pairNumbers([10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 50])) // 3
```