# Big O of "in" operator inside for loop

Tags: javascript, big-o

Consider this snippet:

```
const obj1 = {1:1, 2:1, 3:1}
const obj2 = {1:1, 4:1, 9:1}

for(let key in obj1){
    if(!(key ** 2 in obj2)) return false
  }
```

Can the Big O of this algorithm considered O(n) or it should be O(n^2) because of:

```
if(!(key ** 2 in obj2))
```

Is considered to loop through all items (search) of obj2

** Note**: assume the length of obj1 and obj2 are equal

Comment: It depends on an actual implementation of the property lookup algorithm. It's a good be that it's better than linear on any modern JavaScript runtime.

Comment: Why would the big O of `in` operator change when it's in a for loop?

Comment: @Pointy Am I the only one who thought that his concern was that `key ** 2` caused it to be quadratic?

Comment: @Barmar It has nothing to do with key ** 2, my concern was that "in" search is looping through all items, and that will occur inside the outer loop, hence results in O(n^2), but it turns out that "in" search is O(1) as mates mentioned here.

Comment: I figured that out, but I thought it was suspicious that your question was specifically about `key**2`.

Comment: And Googling could have answered your question about the complexity of `in`.

Comment: @Barmar Just wanted to mention, that post was closed as "duplicate" referring to a "python" question, not a Javascript question? 
It might be the same yes, but also it might happen that complexity and implementation differs from one language to another! right?

Comment: Oops, got confused about the language, sorry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700987/performance-of-key-lookup-in-javascript-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JavaScript object is effectively a hash table, so looking up a key is O(1).

The total algorithm therefore is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that the `in` is not looping through all the items, but works like a hashtable. So I would say its O(n).