# How check the state of individual checkbox in reactjs (material-table)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, material-table

I am having a table which will contain list of students fetched from a database. When I click each student row a modal popup will be shown containing another table of 4 rows and 3 columns. Each column in the modal will contain 4 checkboxes. When I click a checkbox I want to change the status column of that row from 'pending' to 'paid' and also the the badge property type from 'danger' to 'success'. The problem is when I click a checkbox it changes all the columns status from 'pending' to 'paid' instead of just changing that single single row.

Here is my code

```
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  Badge,
  TableFooter,
  TableRow,
  TableHeader,
  TableContainer,
  Input,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter,
  Button,
} from "@windmill/react-ui";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import AddBox from "@material-ui/icons/AddBox";
import ArrowDownward from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward";
import Check from "@material-ui/icons/Check";
import ChevronLeft from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRight from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import Clear from "@material-ui/icons/Clear";
import DeleteOutline from "@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline";
import Edit from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import FilterList from "@material-ui/icons/FilterList";
import FirstPage from "@material-ui/icons/FirstPage";
import LastPage from "@material-ui/icons/LastPage";
import Remove from "@material-ui/icons/Remove";
import SaveAlt from "@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt";

import Search from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import ViewColumn from "@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn";
import React, { forwardRef, useState } from "react";
const Admin = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [id, setId] = useState("");

  function openModal(ids) {
    setId(ids.studentId);
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  }
  function closeModal() {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  }

  const tableIcons = {
    Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />
    )),
    Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
    FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />
    )),
    ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
    SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />
    )),
    ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />
    )),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />),
  };
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("pending");
  const [badge, setBadge] = useState("danger");

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    //Do something if checkbox is clicked
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setStatus("paid");
      setBadge("success");
    } else {
      setStatus("pending");
      setBadge("danger");
    }
  };

  // Table to be rendered in the modal
  function renderTable() {
    return (
      <TableContainer>
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Dues</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Amount</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Status</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>
                <div className='flex items-center text-sm'>
                  <span className='font-semibold ml-2'>Level 100</span>
                </div>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <span className='text-sm'>100</span>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Badge type={badge}>{status}</Badge>
                <Input
                  type='checkbox'
                  className='ml-6'
                  onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
                />
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>
                <div className='flex items-center text-sm'>
                  <span className='font-semibold ml-2'>Level 200</span>
                </div>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <span className='text-sm'>100</span>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Badge type={badge}>{status}</Badge>
                <Input
                  type='checkbox'
                  className='ml-6'
                  onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
                />
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>
                <div className='flex items-center text-sm'>
                  <span className='font-semibold ml-2'>Level 300</span>
                </div>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <span className='text-sm'>100</span>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Badge type={badge}>{status}</Badge>
                <Input
                  type='checkbox'
                  className='ml-6'
                  onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
                />
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>
                <div className='flex items-center text-sm'>
                  <span className='font-semibold ml-2'>Level 400</span>
                </div>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <span className='text-sm'>100</span>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Badge type={badge}>{status}</Badge>
                <Input
                  type='checkbox'
                  className='ml-6'
                  onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
                />
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
        <TableFooter></TableFooter>
      </TableContainer>
    );
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {/* Modal popup */}
      <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={closeModal}>
        <ModalHeader>{id}</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>{renderTable()}</ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button
            className='w-full sm:w-auto'
            layout='outline'
            onClick={closeModal}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button className='w-full sm:w-auto'>Accept</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>

      <MaterialTable
        icons={tableIcons}
        columns={[
          { title: "Student ID", field: "studentId" },
          { title: "Level", field: "level" },
          { title: "Programme", field: "programme" },
        ]}
        data={[
          {
            studentId: "UG0222021",
            level: "200",
            programme: "BCOM",
          },
          {
            studentId: "UG0199821",
            level: "200",
            programme: "BCOM",
          },
        ]}
        title='Students Information'
        onRowClick={(event, rowData) => openModal(rowData)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Admin;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general purpose way of doing this, I've taken the liberty to use typescript since it's so much easier to show what is happening.

```
 const initialStatuses = {
  inputLevel100: "pending",
  inputLevel200: "pending",
  inputLevel300: "pending",
  inputLevel400: "pending",
 }

 const initialBadges = {
  inputLevel100: "danger",
  inputLevel200: "danger",
  inputLevel300: "danger",
  inputLevel400: "danger",
 }

 const [status, setStatus] = React.useState<{ [key: string]: string }>(initialBadges);
 const [badge, setBadge] = React.useState<{ [key: string]: string }>(initialStatuses);

 const handleClick = (e: { target: { checked: boolean; name: string} }) => {
 const name = e.target.name;

 if (e.target.checked) {
  setBadge({
    ...badge,
    [name]: "success",
  });
  
  setStatus({
   ...status,
   [name]: "paid",
  });
 }  

};
```

You can get the value of either the status or badge by simply saying

```
status["Level200"] // Should return either "pending" or "paid"
```

or

```
badge["Level200"] // Should return either "danger" or "success"
```

This should be very performant (see [Performance of key lookup in JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700987/performance-of-key-lookup-in-javascript-object) to learn more)

But, more importantly you now have a general purpose way of adding more statuses and badges without having to worry about adding `useState` for each newly added status or badge

Plus, another added advantage of this approach is that you can (say) get the list of statuses and badges from a remote api or (say) have a `statuses.js` file that has a list of statuses & a `badges.js` file on the client side that you can then map over. This then makes your code easier to extend and removing/adding new statuses and badges becomes trivial

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because you're using one state for all status badges. you should use different states to manage every badge. You could add the `name` attribute to every input so you can see which input is changing in the `handleClick` function and then update the related state. You could add below code:

```
/* states */
const[statusOfLevel100, setStatusOfLevel100] = useState('pending')
const[statusOfLevel200, setStatusOfLevel200] = useState('pending')
const[statusOfLevel300, setStatusOfLevel300] = useState('pending')
const[statusOfLevel400, setStatusOfLevel400] = useState('pending')
const[badgeOfLevel100, setBadgeOfLevel100] = useState('danger')
const[badgeOfLevel200, setBadgeOfLevel200] = useState('danger')
const[badgeOfLevel300, setBadgeOfLevel300] = useState('danger')
const[badgeOfLevel400, setBadgeOfLevel400] = useState('danger')
...
/* handleClick function */
const handleClick = (e) => {
switch (e.target.name) {
  case 'inputLevel100':
    if(e.target.checked) {
      setStatusOfLevel100('paid')
      setBadgeOfLevel100('success')
    } else {
      setStatusOfLevel100('pending')
      setBadgeOfLevel100('danger')
    }
    break;
case 'inputLevel200':
    if(e.target.checked) {
      setStatusOfLevel200('paid')
      setBadgeOfLevel200('success')
    } else {
      setStatusOfLevel200('pending')
      setBadgeOfLevel200('danger')
    }
    break;
case 'inputLevel300':
    if(e.target.checked) {
      setStatusOfLevel300('paid')
      setBadgeOfLevel300('success')
    } else {
      setStatusOfLevel300('pending')
      setBadgeOfLevel300('danger')
    }
    break;
case 'inputLevel400':
    if(e.target.checked) {
      setStatusOfLevel400('paid')
      setBadgeOfLevel400('success')
    } else {
      setStatusOfLevel400('pending')
      setBadgeOfLevel400('danger')
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: This only works partially. When I click a checkbox of a row it works but also effects the checkbox of the other rows. So say if i clicked the checkbox of level100, it changes from pending to paid but the level100 of other rows are also affected because they all use the same state.