# Javascript Dictionary

Tags: javascript

I am referencing this post:

[are there dictionaries in javascript like python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559070/are-there-dictionaries-in-javascript-like-python)

My dictionary looks like this:

```
        states_dictionary = {
         "1":["60","purple","1t"],
         "2":["50","blue","2t"],
         "3":["40", "red","3t"],
         "4":["30","yellow","4t"],
         "5":["20","black","5t"],
         "6":["10", "green","6t"],
         "7":["10", "orange","7t"]
    };
```

I am have a variable called `reading` that on first iteration, is "1". I want to get the color corresponding to this variable using a dictionary.

I use:

```
color = states_dictionary.reading[1]
```

However, I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

Why is this?

Comment: So a dictionary with numeric keys is basically an array...

Comment: @elclanrs True, never thought about it that way

Comment: @elclanrs can this still be implemented though?

Comment: `color = states_dictionary[reading][1]` gives your `purple`

Comment: It's `states_dictionary[String(reading)]` because the key is the string `'1'` not the integer `1`.

Comment: @Brunt: Doesn't matter. It will be automatically coerced to a string.

Comment: @Brunt: Would you use `states_dictionary[String(reading)][String(1)]` as well?

Comment: @MattBurland alright I wasn't sure.
Bergi: no, the value is an array so you don't have to "stringify" the index to access the color ;) `states_dictionary[reading][1]` or `states_dictionary[String(reading)][1]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for here:

```
color = states_dictionary.reading[1];
```

Is the property called `reading` of the object `states_dictionary`. `states_dictionary` does not have a property called `reading`, so that returns undefined. You can't call any properties of `undefined`, so you get the error you observe.

If `reading` is a variable like this:

```
var reading = 1; // or even "1"
```

Then you can do this:

```
color = states_dictionary[reading][1];
```

And `color` will get the value `purple`.

Use the bracket notation to dynamically access a property using a variable rather than the dot notation. For example these:

```
var foo = someObj.Foo;
var foo = someObj["Foo"];
```

Are equivalent. But these two:

```
var bar = "Foo";
var foo = someObj.bar;
var foo = someObj[bar];
```

Are not.