# For JavaScript coding interviews what do we call the object {}?

Tags: javascript

I'm prepping for my coding interviews using LeetCode and JavaScript. In video solutions people are referring to using the JavaScript object `{}` as using a Hashmap or Hashtable. Would it be wrong if I called it an object during the interview?

Comment: That's what most people here call it. It's implemented as a hash table, but no one calls it that.

Comment: I would either call it object or [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#object_literals), depending on the context.

Comment: You may call it dictionary, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559070/are-there-dictionaries-in-javascript-like-python)

Comment: How about casually referring to a JS `Object` instance as _"Bag of key value pairs"_? ... btw `{}` in its  written form is called an object literal, and it does _materialize_ as an empty object (thus it features not a single own property).

Answer (score 0):

The correct terminology in JavaScript is Object [Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)