# JavaScript dictionary with names

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary in JavaScript like the following:

```
myMappings = [
    { "Name": 10%},
    { "Phone": 10%},
    { "Address": 50%},
    { "Zip": 10%},
    { "Comments": 20%}
]
```

I want to populate an HTML table later and want to set the titles of table to the first column of myMappings and the width of columns to the second. Is there a clean way to do it?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130543/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-hashtable-implementation-in-javascript

Comment: The title does not contain a question.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The main problem I see with what you have is that it's difficult to loop through, for populating a table.

Simply use an array of arrays:

```
var myMappings = [
    ["Name", "10%"], // Note the quotes around "10%"
    ["Phone", "10%"],
    // etc..
];
```

... which simplifies access:

```
myMappings[0][0]; // column name
myMappings[0][1]; // column width
```

---

Alternatively:

```
var myMappings = {
    names: ["Name", "Phone", etc...],
    widths: ["10%", "10%", etc...]
};
```

And access with:

```
myMappings.names[0];
myMappings.widths[0];
```

Comment: you are better of using an array of objects, just like `[{'Phone':'10%','Name':'10%'},{},{}]`. If you are using an array, you are specifically using a certain "order" which in this case does not matter.

Answer (score 70):

Another approach would be to have an array of objects, with each individual object holding the properties of a column. This slightly changes the structure of "myMappings", but makes it easy to work with:

```
var myMappings = [
    { title: "Name", width: "10%" },
    { title: "Phone", width: "10%" },
    { title: "Address", width: "50%" },
    { title: "Zip", width: "10%" },
    { title: "Comments", width: "20%" }
];
```

Then you could easily iterate through all your "columns" with a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myMappings.length; i += 1) {
    // myMappings[i].title ...
    // myMappings[i].width ...
}
```

Comment: this is probably the solution you're looking for

Answer (score 23):

You may be trying to use a JSON object:

```
var myMappings = { "name": "10%", "phone": "10%", "address": "50%", etc.. }
```

To access:

```
myMappings.name;
myMappings.phone;
etc..
```

Comment: That is an object literal, not JSON.

Comment: The first 3 letters of JSON is enough: JavaScript Object. "JavaScript Object Notation object" sounds weird.

Comment: @box9 haha you're correct. that's a pleonasm, like ATM machine. good catch, although i think it's pretty common to say JSON object

Comment: My point is really that JSON is a data format whereas an object literal is a piece of JavaScript code.

Answer (score 23):

An object technically is a dictionary.

```
var myMappings = {
    mykey1: 'myValue',
    mykey2: 'myValue'
};

var myVal = myMappings['myKey1'];

alert(myVal); // myValue
```

You can even loop through one.

```
for(var key in myMappings) {
    var myVal = myMappings[key];
    alert(myVal);
}
```

There is no reason whatsoever to reinvent the wheel. And of course, assignment goes like:

```
myMappings['mykey3'] = 'my value';
```

And ContainsKey:

```
if (myMappings.hasOwnProperty('myKey3')) {
    alert('key already exists!');
}
```

I suggest you follow this: http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/

Comment: The link seems to be (effectively) broken: *"Error establishing a database connection"*

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
var myMappings = {
    "Name":     "10%",
    "Phone":    "10%",
    "Address":  "50%",
    "Zip":      "10%",
    "Comments": "20%"
}

// Access is like this
myMappings["Name"] // Returns "10%"
myMappings.Name // The same thing as above

// To loop through...
for(var title in myMappings) {
    // Do whatever with myMappings[title]
}
```

Comment: Or `myMappings.Name` to access.

Comment: @doorknob Yeah that too

Comment: @kid `Object.value` is actually preferred over `Object['value']`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest not using an array unless you have multiple objects to consider. There isn't anything wrong this statement:

```
var myMappings = {
    "Name": 0.1,
    "Phone": 0.1,
    "Address": 0.5,
    "Zip": 0.1,
    "Comments": 0.2
};

for (var col in myMappings) {
    alert((myMappings[col] * 100) + "%");
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with it if order is important, as the question implies it is.

Answer (score 4):

An easier, native and more efficient way of emulating a dict in JavaScript than a hash table:

It also exploits that JavaScript is weakly typed. Rather type inference.

Here's how (an excerpt from Google Chrome's console):

```
var myDict = {};

myDict.one = 1;
1

myDict.two = 2;
2

if (myDict.hasOwnProperty('three'))
{
  console.log(myDict.two);
}
else
{
  console.log('Key does not exist!');
}
Key does not exist! VM361:8

if (myDict.hasOwnProperty('two'))
{
  console.log(myDict.two);
}
else
{
  console.log('Key does not exist!');
}
2 VM362:4

Object.keys(myDict);
["one", "two"]

delete(myDict.two);
true

myDict.hasOwnProperty('two');
false

myDict.two
undefined

myDict.one
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dictionary that will take any type of key as long as the toString() property returns unique values. The dictionary uses anything as the value for the key value pair.

See *[Would JavaScript Benefit from a Dictionary Object](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/684815/Would-JavaScript-Benefit-from-a-Dictionary-Object)*.

To use the dictionary as is:

```
var dictFact = new Dict();
var myDict = dictFact.New();
myDict.addOrUpdate("key1", "Value1");
myDict.addOrUpdate("key2", "Value2");
myDict.addOrUpdate("keyN", "ValueN");
```

The dictionary code is below:

```
/*
* Dictionary Factory Object
* Holds common object functions. similar to V-Table
* this.New() used to create new dictionary objects
* Uses Object.defineProperties so won't work on older browsers.
* Browser Compatibility (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)
*      Firefox (Gecko) 4.0 (2), Chrome 5, Internet Explorer 9, Opera 11.60, Safari 5
*/
function Dict() {

    /*
    * Create a new Dictionary
    */
    this.New = function () {
        return new dict();
    };

    /*
    * Return argument f if it is a function otherwise return undefined
    */
    function ensureF(f) {
        if (isFunct(f)) {
            return f;
        }
    }

    function isFunct(f) {
        return (typeof f == "function");
    }

    /*
    * Add a "_" as first character just to be sure valid property name
    */
    function makeKey(k) {
        return "_" + k;
    };

    /*
    * Key Value Pair object - held in array
    */
    function newkvp(key, value) {
        return {
            key: key,
            value: value,
            toString: function () { return this.key; },
            valueOf: function () { return this.key; }
        };
    };

    /*
    * Return the current set of keys.
    */
    function keys(a) {
        // remove the leading "-" character from the keys
        return a.map(function (e) { return e.key.substr(1); });
        // Alternative: Requires Opera 12 vs. 11.60
        // -- Must pass the internal object instead of the array
        // -- Still need to remove the leading "-" to return user key values
        //    Object.keys(o).map(function (e) { return e.key.substr(1); });
    };

    /*
    * Return the current set of values.
    */
    function values(a) {
        return a.map(function(e) { return e.value; } );
    };

    /*
    * Return the current set of key value pairs.
    */
    function kvPs(a) {
        // Remove the leading "-" character from the keys
        return a.map(function (e) { return newkvp(e.key.substr(1), e.value); });
    }

    /*
    * Returns true if key exists in the dictionary.
    * k - Key to check (with the leading "_" character)
    */
    function exists(k, o) {
        return o.hasOwnProperty(k);
    }

    /*
    * Array Map implementation
    */
    function map(a, f) {
        if (!isFunct(f)) { return; }
        return a.map(function (e, i) { return f(e.value, i); });
    }

    /*
    * Array Every implementation
    */
    function every(a, f) {
        if (!isFunct(f)) { return; }
        return a.every(function (e, i) { return f(e.value, i) });
    }

    /*
    * Returns subset of "values" where function "f" returns true for the "value"
    */
    function filter(a, f) {
        if (!isFunct(f)) {return; }
        var ret = a.filter(function (e, i) { return f(e.value, i); });
        // if anything returned by array.filter, then get the "values" from the key value pairs
        if (ret && ret.length > 0) {
            ret = values(ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /*
    * Array Reverse implementation
    */
    function reverse(a, o) {
        a.reverse();
        reindex(a, o, 0);
    }

    /**
    * Randomize array element order in-place.
    * Using Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.
    */
    function shuffle(a, o) {
        var j, t;
        for (var i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
        reindex(a, o, 0);
        return a;
    }
    /*
    * Array Some implementation
    */
    function some(a, f) {
        if (!isFunct(f)) { return; }
        return a.some(function (e, i) { return f(e.value, i) });
    }

    /*
    * Sort the dictionary. Sorts the array and reindexes the object.
    * a - dictionary array
    * o - dictionary object
    * sf - dictionary default sort function (can be undefined)
    * f - sort method sort function argument (can be undefined)
    */
    function sort(a, o, sf, f) {
        var sf1 = f || sf; // sort function  method used if not undefined
        // if there is a customer sort function, use it
        if (isFunct(sf1)) {
            a.sort(function (e1, e2) { return sf1(e1.value, e2.value); });
        }
        else {
            // sort by key values
            a.sort();
        }
        // reindex - adds O(n) to perf
        reindex(a, o, 0);
        // return sorted values (not entire array)
        // adds O(n) to perf
        return values(a);
    };

    /*
    * forEach iteration of "values"
    *   uses "for" loop to allow exiting iteration when function returns true
    */
    function forEach(a, f) {
        if (!isFunct(f)) { return; }
        // use for loop to allow exiting early and not iterating all items
        for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (f(a[i].value, i)) { break; }
        }
    };

    /*
    * forEachR iteration of "values" in reverse order
    *   uses "for" loop to allow exiting iteration when function returns true
    */
    function forEachR(a, f) {
        if (!isFunct(f)) { return; }
        // use for loop to allow exiting early and not iterating all items
        for (var i = a.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            if (f(a[i].value, i)) { break; }
        }
    }

    /*
    * Add a new Key Value Pair, or update the value of an existing key value pair
    */
    function add(key, value, a, o, resort, sf) {
        var k = makeKey(key);
        // Update value if key exists
        if (exists(k, o)) {
            a[o[k]].value = value;
        }
        else {
            // Add a new Key value Pair
            var kvp = newkvp(k, value);
            o[kvp.key] = a.length;
            a.push(kvp);
        }
        // resort if requested
        if (resort) { sort(a, o, sf); }
    };

    /*
    * Removes an existing key value pair and returns the "value" If the key does not exists, returns undefined
    */
    function remove(key, a, o) {
        var k = makeKey(key);
        // return undefined if the key does not exist
        if (!exists(k, o)) { return; }
        // get the array index
        var i = o[k];
        // get the key value pair
        var ret = a[i];
        // remove the array element
        a.splice(i, 1);
        // remove the object property
        delete o[k];
        // reindex the object properties from the remove element to end of the array
        reindex(a, o, i);
        // return the removed value
        return ret.value;
    };

    /*
    * Returns true if key exists in the dictionary.
    * k - Key to check (without the leading "_" character)
    */
    function keyExists(k, o) {
        return exists(makeKey(k), o);
    };

    /*
    * Returns value assocated with "key". Returns undefined if key not found
    */
    function item(key, a, o) {
        var k = makeKey(key);
        if (exists(k, o)) {
            return a[o[k]].value;
        }
    }

    /*
    * changes index values held by object properties to match the array index location
    * Called after sorting or removing
    */
    function reindex(a, o, i){
        for (var j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
            o[a[j].key] = j;
        }
    }

    /*
    * The "real dictionary"
    */
    function dict() {
        var _a = [];
        var _o = {};
        var _sortF;

        Object.defineProperties(this, {
            "length": { get: function () { return _a.length; }, enumerable: true },
            "keys": { get: function() { return keys(_a); }, enumerable: true },
            "values": { get: function() { return values(_a); }, enumerable: true },
            "keyValuePairs": { get: function() { return kvPs(_a); }, enumerable: true},
            "sortFunction": { get: function() { return _sortF; }, set: function(funct) { _sortF = ensureF(funct); }, enumerable: true }
        });

        // Array Methods - Only modification to not pass the actual array to the callback function
        this.map = function(funct) { return map(_a, funct); };
        this.every = function(funct) { return every(_a, funct); };
        this.filter = function(funct) { return filter(_a, funct); };
        this.reverse = function() { reverse(_a, _o); };
        this.shuffle = function () { return shuffle(_a, _o); };
        this.some = function(funct) { return some(_a, funct); };
        this.sort = function(funct) { return sort(_a, _o, _sortF, funct); };

        // Array Methods - Modified aborts when funct returns true.
        this.forEach = function (funct) { forEach(_a, funct) };

        // forEach in reverse order
        this.forEachRev = function (funct) { forEachR(_a, funct) };

        // Dictionary Methods
        this.addOrUpdate = function(key, value, resort) { return add(key, value, _a, _o, resort, _sortF); };
        this.remove = function(key) { return remove(key, _a, _o); };
        this.exists = function(key) { return keyExists(key, _o); };
        this.item = function(key) { return item(key, _a, _o); };
        this.get = function (index) { if (index > -1 && index < _a.length) { return _a[index].value; } } ,
        this.clear = function() { _a = []; _o = {}; };

        return this;
    }

    return this;
}
```