# Accessing a JSON object outside its callback method

Tags: javascript, json

I am writing a function, which will connect to a server and retrieve a JSON object. It will process it and return a normal array with values to be loaded in some HTML tag. I know it can be done using other ways, but I am using the following code.

```
var names = new Array();
function fetch (key) {
  var url = 'server/server.php?key=' + key
  $.getJSON(url , sett = function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      names[key] = value['name'];
    });
    console.log(names);//works and print the values
  });
  console.log(names);//doesn't work, shows and empty array
}
```

I want to return an array which will hold the values filtered by jQuery each, so this function can work as a standard function for any big application. How it can be done?

Comment: It won't work because you have to wait until the data has been fetched. Put your code inside `.getJSON`.

Comment: The way I do it (which may not be the best because I'm a beginner myself) is to equate the json values to global values within the callback, the last statement of which is a function call to an overall processing function. I'll be interested to see how those with more knowledge than I advise doing it.

Comment: callbacks are good way to do that but the official way is using the deferred or custom events which fires upon completion of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in comments, your ajax request will take some time (short amount of time, but still time), so your `console.log` located outside of the ajax call will execute before the ajax call is complete, showing the original, empty array.

You could add a callback parameter to your `fetch` function...

so...

```
function fetch (key, callback) {
  var url = 'server/server.php?key=' + key
  $.getJSON(url , sett = function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      names[key] = value['name'];
    });
    // call callback inside the getJSON callback    
    callback && callback.call(this, names);
  });
}
```

Now, your callback function will have your `names` array as argument one.

```
fetch(some_key, function(names){
  console.log(names); //should work!
});
```

Comment: No problem, make sure to accept the answer so others can easily find the top response

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying to add your array elements to the array.

```
names.push(value['name']);
```

If you want more of dictionary approach (which it seems like you do) try this.

[JavaScript dictionary with names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745960/javascript-dictionary-with-names)

Also, after reading the other comments and thinking more... you may want to move your code that loops over the results into the 'success' callback.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Good luck!

Comment: Or do you mean `Objects`... `var names = {};`

Comment: Yes, you could also define a javascript class to hold the values

http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Then just create an array of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this.  But the following should work:

```
var names = new Array();
function fetch (key) {
  var url = 'server/server.php?key=' + key
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "get",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        names[key] = value['name'];
      });
      console.log(names); // this should still work
    },
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
  });
  console.log(names); // this should now work
}
```

However, you really should try to stay away from synchronous requests.