# Reading JSON to JQuery is slowing down server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am not sure I am doing this correctly. Basically, my Jquery script calls a 500kb json file and loads it into an array, after that is done the rest of the page loads.

The first request happens fine, but if I refresh the browser it gets slower each time until eventually it is completely sluggish. What's more is that it seems the whole server might be affected because I cannot upload via FTP either until I wait a little bit.

Any thoughts/help would be much appreciated. There is really nothing else running. If I remove this block then the page loads fine.

```
var content = array[];
function getData() {
    //loader with progress bar - load 500kb json file
    $.getJSON('lib/soundCloudData.json', function(data){
          $.each(data, function (index, item) {          
                content.push(item);
             });
                     //remove loader and get main page
             runSetup()
    });
 }
```

Comment: Did you check the details with eg. Chrome's Developer Tools? Which browsers exactly did you try?

Comment: @UmurKontacı `runSetup()` just arranges some divs to present the main page. If I comment out the json file and just `runSetup` everything works fine

Comment: @Tadeck I am trying in Chrome and Safari w the same results. I am looking in Chromes task manager and there is nothing unusual, no cpu spikes or excessive memory allocation. I also looked in my whm's `system health` section. Again, nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: @frankie, are you calling `getData()` only once per full page load?

Comment: @frankie - could you make a fiddle with your example, it would really help to figure this one out

Comment: @Dogbert  - yes, just once.

Comment: @frankie, a fiddle would be very helpful. Or a direct link to the page if fiddle is not possible.

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, you are right. I haven't used jsfiddle too much but will try to get my head around it and post there. thanks again.

Comment: @Dogbert here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chronopolis/hV2PV/ It seems to be performing much better. But I wonder if that's a result of  the json being hosted on a scalable system (dropbox).

Comment: As of the information you gave, there is nothing going wrong. It is very likely that your server is slow.

Comment: I dont understand why you are getting items out of data which is already an array and putting in new array content and then looping it again. you are unnecessarily making $.each loop two times which ll make ur browser slow coz u ve too many entries.

Comment: @HarryBomrah is there a way I can put the json data right into an array that Jquery can use? I was under the impression that I have to parse it out of json and then create a new array for the client. Is this not the case?

Comment: Your json object is already an array. for ex this is ur object data = {"name":"xxx","age":30}, you ve two ways to access this. first is data.name and other is data['name'], both will give u the same result. you dont ve to parse it out. its already parsed by getJSON method.

Comment: @HarryBomrah that solved the problem. I just directly assigned `content` to `data` and the page loads about 10 times faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just a guess,

your 500 KB JSON file takes a while in loading (while means in milliseconds), but it's asynchronous method (it keeps running while the control moves on).

so basically you are calling your runsetup() method while the data is not ready, may be that is causing the problem.

try using a callback for getJSON method and inside that call back run your setup method.

Comment: Except that `runSetup()` _is_ in the callback to `getJSON()`

Comment: no not that way, the way you coded it executes right after the each loop. So it reads the each loop start working with the JSON file and moves on while the reading JSON is still in progress.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313247/accessing-a-json-object-outside-its-callback-method