# Regex to remove duplicate Characters completely (without leaving them behind)

Tags: regex

I need a regex to remove duplicate characters from a string like so:
`abcdeafghid` to `bcefghi`, removing `a` and `d`

I have no idea how I would go about this honestly. I can find a lot about removing duplicates, but they always leave behind one instance of the duplicated character.

The order of the characters at the end doesn't matter, but since I'm working with CJK languages it should support those. How would I go about this?

Comment: Do you need a regex for this? There are other more performant algorithms to resolve this.

Comment: What programming language are you using, as the answer to this question will likely influence the answer we give you.

Comment: @Cristik I don't necessarily need regex, it'd just be convinient. If you can provide anything that solves the problem please share it with me, though I'd prefer it to be in Haskell, C or Javascript (as those are the languages I can actually understand)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen above also answers your question

Comment: Make a map, using as key each different character of your string and using as value the times that char appears in the String. Then, find in the map the chars that appears more the one time and then remove them from the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrelevant of you language you can use the pseudocode below:

```
Dictionary dict 
for i = 0 to Len(your_string)
  if Not(dict.Exits(your_string[i])) then 
     dict.Add(your_string[i],1)
  else
     dict[your_string[i]] += 1
  end if
Next i

int index = 0 
while 1
  if dict[your_string[index]] > 1 then
   your_string = replace(your_string, your_string[index],"")
   index = 0
  else 
   index +=1
   if index >= Len(your_string) then break
  end if  
end while
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how I would go about the dict dictionary though, could you provide an example of how to use that in the context of a language?

Comment: VBA: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234?wa=wsignin1.0 C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Neither of these I can use, due to not being on a platform that supports VBA or C# libraries

Comment: Virtually all languages support Dictionaries (Javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745960/javascript-dictionary-with-names). Just google for the language you need. If Dictionaries are not available as an object use simply a binary representation of your array of characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this one of two ways:

1. build a string character by character for each unique character in the string
2. use a regex to globally eliminate characters that exist more than once.

One line in Python:

```
>>> s='abcdeafghid'
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if s.count(c)==1) # only keep the ones that are singular
'bcefghi'
```

Or, filter out the ones that have more than one:

```
>>> s='abcdeafghid'
>>> filter(lambda c: s.count(c)==1, s)
'bcefghi'
```

In Perl you would create a hash with the counts of each character in the string then either delete the character with a regex or add in if the count is equal to 1:

```
my $s='abcdeafghid';
my %h;

$h{$_}++ foreach (split //, $s);    # count of all characters

while(my($k, $v) = each %h){ $s =~ s/$k//g if $v>1}

print $s;
```

Or,

```
my $s='abcdeafghid';
my %h;
my $new='';

$h{$_}++ foreach (split //, $s);

foreach (split //, $s) { $new.=$_ if $h{$_}==1}

print $new;
```