# What's the most appropriate data structure for this? (Are there disadvantages or caveats to having an Array with gaps in it?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

I basically need a dictionary of certain numbers to other values. I'll start with:

```
var o = /*??????*/
```

And then:

```
o[4] = foo;
o[8] = bar;
```

You'll notice that the indexes are far from sequential, though as keys they are definitely significant.

What are the disadvantages to using an array for this, or should I just be using numeric keys on an object?

Comment: Can you tell us what will be the purpose of the resulting structure?

Comment: If the order of the data is sequential (and must remain so), you may want to use an array. Otherwise, for non-sequential data (where order doesn't matter), probably better off sticking with an object. More info on the problem you're actually solving would help...

Comment: You haven't told us the range of numbers, and you haven't described the set of operations that you need to carry out.

Comment: I need to be able to retrieve the value of foo using the value `4`, and I need to be able to save other retrievable values by other numbers. It's just a dictionary. I may also need iteration, and of course, `Array` methods and other niceties won't hurt me if I don't use them, and they might be nice to have, depending on what caveats there are to using arrays like this. So, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: By dictionary I assume you are looking for a python like dictionary AKA a hash table. Here is how to implement it in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130543/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-hashtable-implementation-in-javascript

Comment: A very interesting answer to another question (especially the for-in part) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/1619738).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick to 'plain' objects. Arrays imply sequential iteration, which will give people the wrong idea — you wouldn't want to shift, splice or push to this object, which is essentially a hash.

If the incidentally numeric keys do not represent an ordered sequence, you're just giving the wrong idea to anyone else (not to mention yourself) when they approach the code.

Comment: This is very importatnt, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects are sparse, and arrays are just specialized objects with an auto-maintained length property (which is actually one larger than the largest index, not the number of defined elements) and some additional methods. You are safe either way; use an array if you need it's extra features, and an object otherwise.

Comment: I guess my question is just how nicely arrays' extra features would play nice with my nonsequential data.

Comment: @user3025492 Not very well, sometimes — sparse arrays (ie those that have empty indices when a higher index does exist) cause bizarre errors in IE8 and lower. I ran into this when using lodash's each method on a genuine large array once (the source was fixed). Regardless of engine implementations, the cognitive implications are bad: you're unsure yourself and are likely to be in future; others reading your code will probably fare worse. At the end of the day, Array's methods are utterly inappropriate for this dictionary and do not on the face of it present any advantage: use plain Objects!

Comment: @Barney  you are right. i prefer use array as list, use plain object when you need a map

Comment: @Barney AFAIC IE BS doesn't count. But the rest of your comment makes fine sense.